# Is there any other way to fix this problem besides using !importand after every line css

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on an online code editor. (like jsfiddle codepen etc...)

I got everything working, but I ran into one problem; If a user does something like this:

```
button { 
 background-color: red;
}
```

It also changes the properties of my "run code" and "reset" button I made.

same thing with other things like a div;

```
div {
padding: 500em;
}
```

because this will also change the div's Im using in my own code.

I fixed the issue using !importand tags after every line in my css but I'm wordering if there is any other way to fix this? or is !importand really the only way.

Comment: If by "an online code editor" you mean something like jsfiddle, codepen or similar - those all work around any such issues, by simply showing the results in an (i)frame.

Comment: Oh woah, yeah i didn't think of that, that makes my life much easier, thanks!

Comment: A proper use of css selectors is requires here. The more complex the page, the more specific the selectors need to be. You can target an element by an id or class or a certain hierarchy. For example `button.redClass {}`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe). To do this you can use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

A more original solution would be to create a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) with a shadow root (which isolate the style too). The [support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_shadowroot) for this is not too bad even if it's fairly new :
[image: support for shadow root api]

But, I've used it myself and it's a little bit harder to understand at first